# Hash Table Chaining

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable, chaining

```
 public void put(int key, int value) {
        int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
        if (table[hash] == null)
            table[hash] = new LinkedHashEntry(key, value);
        else {
            LinkedHashEntry entry = table[hash];
            while (entry.getNext() != null && entry.getKey() != key)
                entry = entry.getNext();
            if (entry.getKey() == key)
                entry.setValue(value);
            else
                entry.setNext(new LinkedHashEntry(key, value));
        }
    }
```

I'm just learning the concept of hash table chaining and i thought if we add a new item . we will see if the key of the item is existed, if so, we just link it to the same node with the same key .But just found this code online under the Hash table chaining title but it doesn't do what i have supposed to .it's either i'm wrong or this code.this part confuses me the most  :

```
if (entry.getKey() == key)
                entry.setValue(value);
```

this is going to do as same as what it does in open address hashing .you just replace the old node with the new one .just need a complete definition with example of hash table and hash table chaining and their differences .

Thanks,

Comment: This code looks correct. The line you mention uses the existing node and overwrites the value, which is correct. Could you please be more specific as to your confusion?

Comment: The part that's different in chaining is the `else` case.

Answer (score 0):

Hash table chain is a kind of hash table's implementation. It is used to reduce hashing hash collision. For example, a item named A's hash value is 100, and another item has already existed on table[100]. To input item A, in the case of open address hashing, item A will insert with index 101 in the table, which will add the chance of hash collision(if another item's hash value is 101 in the future). And hash table chain will not.